# Display a single data in a textview

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

can some one give me an example for displaying single data from SQLite database and display it in a textview, with a Search box and a search button.

my problem is i want to search data in database with ID that will input to a search box the when i hit the button it will display some information in textview.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: my problem is i want to search data in database with ID that will input to a search box the when i hit the button it will display some information in textview.

Answer (score 0):

Show textview you can user cursor and use:

```
                        if (database != null) {
                        Cursor cursor = database.query(YOURTABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                            textview.setText(cursor.getString(yourcolumn));
                            cursor.moveToNext();


                        }
                        cursor.close();
```

For search box: (Auto search after 0,5 second) or you can setonclick for button

```
editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        private Timer timer = new Timer();
        private final long DELAY = 500; // in ms

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO: do what you need here (refresh list)
                    // you will probably need to use runOnUiThread(Runnable action) for some specific actions

                }

            }, DELAY);
              //Search data by Cursor
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this help!